# Is there a bobble head equivalent in Fallout: New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have been looking around for the standard stat boosters and skill boosters and still haven't seen anything that will boost my S.P.E.C.I.A.L. I was wondering if there are any things hidden away like the bobble heads in 3 that I might be missing.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9358/what-items-should-be-saved-for-turn-ins

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the collectible standpoint, there are 7 [Snowglobes](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Snowglobe). However, these don't give you stats. Instead they can be sold for caps. *A whole heck of a lot of caps.*

To increase your SPECIAL stats, there are [Implants](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Fallout:_New_Vegas_implants) available for purchase, that will increase any stat by +1, as well as Implants to grant health regeneration and increased DT. You can purchase a maximum number of Implants equal to your Endurance score.

To increase skills permanently, there's only [books](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Fallout:_New_Vegas_skill_books) -  4 for each skill except for Repair, for which there are only 3. With the Comprehension perk, each book gives 4 points in it's associated skill, for a maximum of 16 points from books -  12 for Repair.

Comment: can you use implants to raise you endurance to ten and then raise the other stats? or does that mean your base score so there is no way to get all your stats to ten in this fallout?

Comment: Endurance implants do not increase the amount of total implants you can hold. Also, I'm pretty sure you can only get each implant once.

Comment: Of course, you can always increase your Endurance (or any other SPECIAL stats) with the Intense Training perk (assuming you haven't already done it 10 times).

Comment: This is why you basically always want 9 Endurance at the start of the game. A point in Endurance at the start of the game allows a point in another stat. Nine allows all the implants. Pretty easy to afford after cleaning out the casinos, which works since the clinic is right next to one of the Freeside gates.

Answer (score 1):

There's a mod called "The New Bison Steve Hotel and Lucky Casino" (linked [here](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/40433/?)) which adds an opportunity to restore the Bison Steve Hotel and earn a player home. It also comes with bobbleheads scattered throughout the Wasteland. These, however, give you the choice of how much of each stat to add (still only 1 for S.P.E.C.I.A.L), 0, 2, 5 or 10 (I think).