# Where can I find implants?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9672/is-there-a-bobble-head-equivalent-in-fallout-new-vegas/9673#9673) to another Fallout New Vegas question, there are implants available for purchase which will increase SPECIAL stats or grant health regeneration and increased damage threshold.

Where can I find these bad boys?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All non-dlc [implants](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Fallout:_New_Vegas_implants) are at the [New Vegas Medical Clinic](http://www.falloutwiki.com/New_Vegas_Medical_Clinic). Right across the road from the Crimson Caravan Company, just a bit NE of Vegas Proper.