# What items are worth more when brought/sold to a specific NPC(s), rather than to a regular merchant?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

(Inspired by the '[What items should be saved for turn-ins?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9358/what-items-should-be-saved-for-turn-ins)'  question for Fallout: New Vegas.)

In Oblivion, what items should be saved for turn-ins? For example, [Roland Jenseric](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Roland_Jenseric)  of [The Order of the Virtuous Blood](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:The_Order_of_the_Virtuous_Blood_%28faction%29) will pay 250 gold for [Vampire Dust](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Vampire_Dust) which is only 50 gold at 100% value when sold to a merchant (merchants on average, at lower mercantile levels, will buy at only around 50% of the value of an item). This makes it more worth it to sell Vampire Dust to Roland Jenseric, rather than to a regular merchant.

Comment: Can't you just make unlimited money with Alchemy?

Comment: @Hackworth, you could. There are also many other ways to make ridiculous amounts of gold in Oblivion. My question is just about which items, when brought/sold to certain NPCs, will give more reward to the player (compared to selling the same item to a regular merchant).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Made community wiki so others can add)

| Item | NPC | Regular value (gold) | Reward when sold or brought to NPC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Ayleid statues](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Ayleid_Statue#Ayleid_Statue) | [Umbacano](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Umbacano) | 250 | 500 gold per statue; 5,000 extra gold when the tenth statue is delivered |
| [Black Bows](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Black_Bow#Black_Bow) | [Count Marius Caro](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Count_Marius_Caro) | 70 | 100 gold |
| [Nirnroots](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Nirnroot) | [Sinderion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Sinderion) | 0 | One bottle of Elixir of Exploration per set of Nirnroot for the first 100 Nirnroots; 250 gold per batch of 10 Nirnroots afterward (Note that at this point, you may get better value for Nirnroots if you're a master alchemist and [create potions](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Alchemy#Prices_of_Potions) with it instead.) |
| [Shadowbanish Wine](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Shadowbanish_Wine#Shadowbanish_Wine) | [Nerussa](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Nerussa) | 55 | 1,000 gold for the first 6 bottles, 100 gold for each additional bottle |
| [Vampire Dust](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Vampire_Dust) | [Roland Jenseric](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Roland_Jenseric) | 50 | 250 gold |

One-time quest items such as [Ectoplasm](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Ectoplasm) are not included in the above table.

Comment: Does Sinderion pay you for Nirnroots, though? Only after you collect 100, first, and he thus completes his explorer potion, maybe.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer Initially, he won't. However, Nirnroots are worth zero gold, so it's better to bring it to Sinderion for the [related quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Seeking_Your_Roots). Once you collect more than 40, and you're a master alchemist, it might be better to create potions with the Nirnroot, instead.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer Correcting comment above to mean: *Once you collect more than **100*** (not 40). (Can't edit comment older than 5 mins).